# SQL filter between start time of day 0:00 and 22 hours later

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, getdate

I need to create a filter in sql, but I don't know how exactly.

```
WHERE date < ?? /*I need it to be today until 10pm */ and
date >= getdate() /* I used getdate(), but I don't know if it's the best way, as I need it to get entries from 0am*/
```

I apologize if I didn't explain myself properly, but I'll try to explain better if I need to.

Comment: Every DBMS may have different syntax and functions for dates. What's the DBMS you're currently using?

Comment: hello I'm using ssms

Comment: ssms is an interface to the DBMS, examples of dbms' are mysql, sql server, mariadb, postgresql, google bigquery, sqlite, etc..

Comment: ok, I got it. I'm using sql server.

Comment: `GETDATE` returns current date and time. It may help you, though it depends on what the constraints of your filter are. It may require some extra explanation for a full answer.

Comment: You want to ignore anything in hours 22 and 23?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to compare on today at 00:00:00 and today at 22:00:00

First you need to get a Date from the current date with the hour `00:00:00`
This can be done like this

```
select convert(date, getdate())
```

Next you need to get a datetime from the current date with the hour `22:00:00`
This can be done like this

```
select dateadd(hour, 22, convert(datetime2(0), convert(date, getdate())))
```

Now you can use these 2 dates in your where clause like this

```
select *
from   yourTable t
where  t.yourDate > convert(date, getdate())
and    t.yourDate <= dateadd(hour, 22, convert(datetime2(0), convert(date, getdate())))
```

If today is 13/10/2022 than this will retrieve all rows between `13/10/2022 00:00:00` and `13/10/2022 22:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

today until 10pm

```
SELECT DATETIME2FROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()), MONTH(getdate()), DAY(getdate()), 10, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

entries from 0am

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Final :

```
WHERE MyColumnDateTime BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
AND DATETIME2FROMPARTS(YEAR(getdate()), MONTH(getdate()), DAY(getdate()), 22, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```